# Inverse of a particular bijection

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $X := \{ (i,j) \in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \; | \; 1\leq i < j\}$. I know that the function $T: X\longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ defined by $$T(i,j) = \frac 12 j(j-3) + i + 1$$ is a bijection. I am interested in the inverse of $T$. Is it possible to find an explicit formula for the inverse of $T$? Any help or comment would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $j$ be the first positive integer such that $$n\leq {j\choose 2}$$ and let $$ i = n-  \frac 12 j(j-3) -1$$

then the map $$n \mapsto (i,j)$$ is the inverse of the given map.

---

Actually $$j = \Big[{\sqrt{8n+1}+1\over 2}\Big],  $$

where $[x]$ is the first integer not smaller than $x$.